# Correct usage of the word "decimated"?

Tags: meaning

I was reading [this](http://www.theguardian.com/environment/2014/sep/29/earth-lost-50-wildlife-in-40-years-wwf) article about humans destroying 50% of its wildlife in the past 40 years and noticed the word "decimated" in the introduction. I thought decimated meant to destroy a tenth or ten percent of. Can it be used interchangeably? I am assuming that decimated is used more as explaining that a large portion of something has been destroyed.

Also I have two other unrelated questions. Am I suppose to quote the word I am questioning and if so, should I put the question mark inside or outside?

Comment: Please ask separate questions for your unrelated questions.

Comment: Your use of quotes is correct. When you mention (refer to) a word, place it in quotation marks. If the quotation is a question, place the question mark before the end quote.  If the whole sentence is a question, place the quotation mark after the end quote.

Answer (score 4):

[To decimate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/decimate) was used to refer to the killing of every tenth person during Roman times. It is now used to refer to a mass killing or to the destruction  of a large portion of something.

> - To destroy or kill a large part of (a group).
> - To inflict great destruction or damage on: The fawns decimated my rose bushes.
> - To reduce markedly in amount: a profligate heir who decimated his trust fund.

From [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Decimate&searchmode=none):

> - 1600, in reference to the practice of punishing mutinous military units by capital execution of one in every 10, by lot; from Latin decimatus, past participle of decimare (see decimation). Killing one in ten, chosen by lots, from a rebellious city or a mutinous army was a common punishment in classical times. **The word has been used (incorrectly, to the irritation of pedants) since 1660s for "destroy a large portion of."**

Usage note:

> - *Decimate originally referred to the killing of every tenth person, a punishment used in the Roman army for mutinous legions.* **Today this meaning is commonly extended to include the killing of any large proportion of a group.** Sixty-six percent of the Usage Panel accepts this extension in the sentence The Jewish population of Germany was decimated by the war, even though it is common knowledge that the number of Jews killed was much greater than a tenth of the original population. However, when the meaning is further extended to include large-scale destruction other than killing, as in **The supply of fresh produce was decimated by the nuclear accident at Chernobyl,** only 26 percent of the Panel accepts the usage.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decimate%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdecimate%3B%2Cc0): decimate.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 1):

You are falling into the [Etymological Fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy), a belief that the current usage of a word should reflect historic use.

While it may be true that the root was to take one tenth (As a tithe or as a punishment. It is not clear which came first.) that in no way means it has to be used that way now. Sinister has a 'real' meaning of left handed, but it is now used for anything unusual.

For sinister we can see a link. Left handed is unusual, and had connotations of evil, so it expanded its field to include all unusual and creepy things. Decimate, as a punishment by killing one in ten of the population, is very violent and damaging to a community - imagine the summary slaughter of, say, 30 million Americans - and in a similar way its use has expanded to include any violent and damaging event.